# How to connect R to bloomberg in a different computer which has the bloomberg system?

Tags: r, connection, bloomberg

So we have a bloomberg terminal but we needed some data in a different computer using R (Rplpapi). But the blpconnect function doesn't work and we thought maybe we can explore the function itself.

the function's help gives this:-

```
       blpConnect(host = getOption("blpHost", "localhost"), 
        port = getOption("blpPort", 8194L), default = TRUE)
```

I think localhost is the one to change but not sure whether to put IPv4 address (which doesn't work btw)
or something else of the computer that actually has the bloomberg?

Thanks!

Comment: Bloomberg's Terms of Service pretty much prohibit exactly this.

Comment: cool, is it written specifically somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

on the desktop API page (DAPI) take a look at "Server API" / "SAPI". You need a server API instance running on the machine you're trying to connect to.